# Will Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Base have .net framework 4.5 in Amazon ec2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Will **Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Base** have .net framework 4.5 in Amazon ec2 ?

I am setting up an Ami and wanted to use the free tier in Windows server 2012. I have a Asp.net MVC application with SQL Server 2012.

Was thinking of using SQL Express 2012

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. The different SKUs are for the licensed product features such as IIS, SQL server, and Active Directory. Features like .NET are available on all SKUs.